# how to use aws jenkins plugin "ecrLogin" in a jenkins step

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecr

I am trying to push a docker image that i build in one Jenkins steps, i have read some tutorials that use
Amazon ECR plugin (but it seems is not been develop anymore/adoption, the Jenkins official AWS plugin from amazon does come with ecrLogin.  but not sure how to use it.

Do i need to put this code into a script{}  ?

```
withAWS(credentials: 'my_credentials'){
    my_loging = ecrLogin()
    sh 'docker --login ${my_loging}'
    sh "docker push my_image_tag" 
}
```

or just pretend that i am doing it like from my local computer

```
withAWS(credentials: 'my_credentials'){
    sh "aws ecr get-login-password --region my_region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin  ecr_url"
    sh "docker push ${docker_full_tag}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd approach is what I've been using, and it works great.

Just make sure that you've properly setup AWSCLI on the **user** which **Jenkins** uses to execute it's pipeline/shell commands.

Comment: We have AWS cli in the Jenkins agents and we will but the sectretkey in the Jenkins credentials in AWS credentials(i think that is also part of the plugin), do we need to do something else?

Comment: That's all you need! Also, just to be sure, you can use 'aws configure' command on your agents. That way, you Jenkins AWS plugin and the default bash shells will have AWS configured by default. Then, you can create a test job and see if 'aws --version' works or not. That will help you debug even better.